# Why isn't my send request work in my expect shell?

Tags: bash, shell, expect

Im trying to write a script to auto deploy my meteor app to a NodeChef server via it's ncli.jar . When launching the jar it asks for several inputs to login to their service, i've managed to login with my expect script but i can't seem to move forward from that. below is my script.

```
expect script:
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn java -jar /usr/bin/nclatest.jar
spawn java -jar /usr/bin/ncli.jar
expect "email address"
send -- "*************"
expect "[ઙ] Signed in as: houset@msoe.edu"
send -- "deploy -i src/deploy/retrospectre\n"
expect "Enter a password"
send -- "C!oudFF7\n"
expect "To agree"
send -- "y\n"
```

It works up to the send -- "*****" command  but not after.
heres is the terminal output
[image: Terminal after running script]

Now it hangs waiting for input from the user to issue an command which i tried to issue via expect's send

Comment: Maybe the `expect` statement is failing because it's supposed to be a pattern and not a string. try just `expect "Signed in"`

Answer (score 2):

Since expect is an extension of  Tcl it has to follow Tcl's [12 syntax rules](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm). One of those is that brackets `[]` are for command substitution. Command substitution can occur within double quotes. You need to change this

```
expect "[ઙ] Signed in as: houset@msoe.edu"
```

to one of these

```tcl
# prevent command substitution by escaping the leading open bracket
expect "\[ઙ] Signed in as: houset@msoe.edu"

# use braces instead of double quotes
expect {[ઙ] Signed in as: houset@msoe.edu}
```

Tcl's `{braces}` are like the shell's `'single quotes'` -- no variable or command substitution is performed within.

If this does not solve the problem, run your expect session with debugging enabled, and you should be able to see what expect is waiting for. Enable debugging in one of two ways:

1. run your script with `expect -d scriptname.exp`
2. add this line to the beginning of your script: `exp_internal 1`